# Disable SSD Read-Cache Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ssd

I need to disable the read-cache in my SSD for benchmarking an application. Is this possible with Windows 7? I just found examples to disable the write-cache.

Comment: You want to disable `Prefetch` and `SuperFetch` so this does indeed seem to be possible.

Comment: Doesn't work. The file is cached anyway, which speeds up the runtime.

Comment: Not perfect, but it works for me: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405868/how-to-invalidate-the-file-system-cache